# Dynamic Create Drop Stored Proc Script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to dynamically create a Drop/Create Script. For that I can calculate the **Create** part as below.

```
SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules
```

**My Query** - can you suggest something for the **Drop Stored Proc** Part...

I am trying a Create/Drop Script for **Stored Proc**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @proc NVARCHAR(511); -- presumably a parameter
SET @proc = N'dbo.sp_help_job';


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @proc + ';
GO
' + definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@proc);

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comparisons of join vs. `OBJECTPROPERTY` method for Pankaj:

[image]

Click to enlarge:

[image]

Don't copy and try to use the OUTPUT from the second screen shot. Why on earth would you do this? This is SQL Server's internal representation of a parameterized version of the query. Let me paste the code so that you aren't doing unexplainable things with what I'm trying to show you:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.[object_id]), m.[object_id]
FROM sys.all_sql_modules AS m
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS o
ON m.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
WHERE o.type = N'P';

SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), [object_id]
FROM sys.all_sql_modules 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsProcedure') = 1;
```

Run those and check the results in profiler. Am I still "wrong" Pankaj? Would you like to waste any more of everyone's time today?